# ng-route is not working, and doesn't throw an error

Tags: angularjs

I use angular js ng-route.
this is my references order:

```
    <script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/app.init.js"></script>   
<script src="js/app/app.routing.js"></script>
```

angular.js - angular reference

angular-route.js - angular route

app.init:

```
angular.module('MyApp',
    [
     'ngRoute'
    ]);
```

app.routing.js:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('MyApp');
sampleApp.config(route);
function route($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/page1', {
        templateUrl: 'js/partials/page1.html'
    }).
    when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: 'js/partials/page2.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/page2'
    });
```

of cource there  is the index.html, where all the references are, there is ng-view.
The problem that nothing happens (and no error shows in the console of the browser)

**EDIT**

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/omWtqBuThq0SyPfL6Abw?p=preview)

it works in plunkr...strangest thing.

Comment: I would advice you to create a jsfiddle or plunker. Since I'm not seeing anything weird right now. Also, include the html in your answer just in case.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot `ng-app="MyApp"` in your index.html. I agree with Gerben: post all you have, and create a plunkr.

Comment: ng-app = 'MyApp'. I probably should post it.
the thing is, when I debug, I see the code enters the first two lines (var sampleApp = angular.module('MyApp');
sampleApp.config(route);) but not the "when" cases when I try to change the page to display

Comment: please set up a plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: @s83, as you said, it works in plunker. What happens in your browser? what is shown?

Comment: well it's very strange, I reversed a few versions ago

Comment: @s83 so the problem was solved?

Comment: Well now it works, but just because of returning to older version. I hope the problem will not return, becuase this one occured suddenly after it was OK, without any explanation.